# How can I set background color of first Row in RecyclerView "Android Application"

Tags: java, android, background, rows, android-recyclerview

I used RecyclerView for displaying items as rows, and all the rows having background color is white. But i want to change first row background color as silver and rest will be white. Please help me.

Comment: i just tried to change background at first position in onBindViewHolder() method. but i didn't find option.

Comment: try if position === 0)
 then change color
else
 default color

Comment: Post that part of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would suggest to have a look at ViewType, based on that you can inflate the correct view.

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)

some references:
http://code2concept.blogspot.de/2015/10/android-multiple-row-layout-using.html

or

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Heterogenous-Layouts-inside-RecyclerView

Answer (score 3):

In the onBindViewHolder

```
if( position == 0){
   holder.view.setBackgroundColor(whatever_color);
}
```

In viewHolder class

```
View view;
public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
  view = itemView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder method of recycleView adapter class, you can use position parameter to perform required functionality. 
In your case, it will be position = 0

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
```